# Can not get jqpuzzle image to be responsive

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the jqpuzzle class to turn an image into a sliding puzzle, this all works great, the only problem is I want to make the images responsive.

I have tried adding the following CSS code to the page but it makes no difference

```
img {

max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

in the jquery.jqpuzzle.full.js page, there is the following line of code.

```
 $srcImg.css({width: '50%', height: '50%', visibility: 'visible'});
```

this was originally set to auto but just kept the image at its original size, if I change the value to 50% then it goes to 50% of the original size of the image etc.  But I can not find a way to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$srcImg.css({width: '50%', height: 'auto', visibility: 'visible'});
```

Comment: Thanks, but no it's still the same, well the height adjusts but the width doesn't shrink with the browser, originally they were both set to auto, but it didn't respond at all.

Comment: Thats strange. Should be 50% of the parent element. Whats is the width of the parent element.

Comment: The image size is 650px wide so actually, it hasn't shrunk, I just took off the parent div although it had no predefined size and it's still the same.

Comment: So I placed it inside a div and it adjusts to 50% of the size of the parent div now,